# Java - Get path of files in package

Tags: java, maven

In my Maven Dependencies is a .jar file i want to look into. For now i'm able to import the jar file:

import test.testnext.*;

In this Package is a .ser file i'm willing to locate and open as a file.

The structure of the jar file:

- package test.testnext:

  . testclass.class

  . testclass1.class

  . testclass2.class

  . testSER.ser

  . testSER1.ser

So: my goal is to locate the *.ser files and beeing able to open the files in my code.

I tried to import the package and get access to the files, but it doesn't worked.

Comment: Please post the code you used

Comment: Use `testclass.class.getResourceAsStream("testSER.ser")`.  Do not attempt to read a .jar entry as a file—it’s not a file at all when it’s part of a .jar file.